# Expected behaviour for running a macOS bundled app as a daemon

Tags: macos, daemon

I have a very basic macOS bundled application with just the empty delegate methods implemented. I want to run this application as a daemon, and so I have created the below daemon property list file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.demo.GUIDaemon.plist</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/vipul.g/MySystemWorkspace/stderr.log</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/vipul.g/MySystemWorkspace/stdout.log</string>

    <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Users/vipul.g/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug/GUIDaemon.app/Contents/MacOS/GUIDaemon</string>

  </dict>
</plist>
```

After loading the daemon, I can see the application running in the Activity monitor, but only the below delegates can be observed getting invoked in the logs. Other delegate like didBecomeActive, willResignActive are not being invoked. Is this the expected behaviour for launching a bundled application as daemon? Also there are some additional items logged, which I m not sure If they are denoting If something went wrong. Can someone confirm what should be expected?

```
024-03-14 18:09:59.452 GUIDaemon[45883:5345352]  inside main.swift
2024-03-14 18:09:59.454 GUIDaemon[45883:5345352] applicationWillFinishLaunching(_:)
2024-03-14 18:09:59.567 GUIDaemon[45883:5345352] TISFileInterrogator updateSystemInputSources false but old data invalid: currentCacheHeaderPtr nonNULL? 0, ->cacheFormatVersion 0, ->magicCookie 00000000, inputSourceTableCountSys 0
Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -17410.
Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -17410 has been replaced with -28673.
Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -30769.
Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -30769 has been replaced with -28674.
Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -14934.
Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -14934 has been replaced with -28675.
2024-03-14 18:09:59.664 GUIDaemon[45883:5345352] applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)
```